# How to skip refetchOnFocus in RTK query when a certain action is in pending state

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I have a bot chat app that uses RTK query. I use `refetchOnFocus` to fetch new messages when a user switches back to the tab. I use optimistic update to update the redux store with the new message. I am facing an issue where if the user is sending a message and focuses out and in to the tab, refetch will cause the new message to be lost, because it has not yet been added to the database, since the send message is still pending.

Is there any neat way to skip this refetch when the sendMessage action is in pending state?